# How to use Private Route using react-router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I want to make secure routes using authentication. I have defined the routes in App.jsx file. I am using "Route" to define which component to render.

In App.jsx

```
<Route 
    path='/dashboard'
    exact={true}
    render={(props) => <Dashboard {...props} user={user} 
    handleChildFunc={this.handleChildFunc}/>}
/>
```

The above code works without any issue. I want to make that secured like below.

```
<PrivateRoute 
    path='/dashboard'
    exact={true}
    render={(props) => <Dashboard {...props} user={user} 
    handleChildFunc={this.handleChildFunc}/>}
/>
```

---

In PrivateRoute.jsx

```
const PrivateRoute = ( props ) => {
  const user = "token from cookie"; // i will fetch token stored in cookie
  if(user !== null) {
    return <Route   />;
  }
  else {
    return <Redirect to="login" />
  }
}
```

If the token is present, render a component. Otherwise, redirect to /login.

Comment: I have made a [gist](https://gist.github.com/EduVencovsky/f8f6c275f42f7352571c92a59309e31d) for private routes, if you wanna check it out.

Comment: You are using <Route path="/signin" component={SignIn} />. But in my case, the Route is defined like this : <Route 
                  path='/dashboard'
                  exact={true}
                  render={(props) => <Dashboard {...props} user={user} 
handleChildFunc={this.handleChildFunc}/>}/>. How can i modify the code?  I am not using component={Component}. Because i want to pass props to the component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The accepted answer is good, but it **does NOT solve** the problem **when we need our component to reflect changes in URL**.

Say, your component has the following code:

```
export const Customer = (props) => {

   const history = useHistory();
   ...

}
```

And you change your URL:

```
const handleGoToPrev = () => {
    history.push(`/app/customer/${prevId}`);
}
```

### The component will not reload!

---

#### An improved solution:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Redirect, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import store from '../store/store';

export const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {

  let isLoggedIn = !!store.getState().data.user;

  return (
    <Route {...rest} render={props => isLoggedIn
      ? (
        <Component key={props.match.params.id || 'empty'} {...props} />
      ) : (
        <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/login', state: { from: props.location } }} />
      )
    } />
  )
}
```

---

#### Usage:

```
<PrivateRoute exact path="/app/customer/:id" component={Customer} />
```

Comment: Wonderful solution for the dynamic url portion and in general.

Comment: You should link to specific answers rather than saying "the accepted answer". That can change.

Answer (score 8):

You can have your `PrivateRoute` like,

```
<PrivateRoute 
    path='/dashboard'
    exact={true}
    component={Dashboard}
    handleChildFunc={this.handleChildFunc}
/>
```

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, handleChildFunc, ...rest }) => {
    const user = "token from cookie";
    return <Route {...rest} render={(props) => (
        user !== null
            ? <Component {...props} user={user} handleChildFunc={handleChildFunc}/>
            : <Redirect to='/login' />
        )} 
    />
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I also found another way to do it.                                                                                                                                                                             const PrivateRoute = ( {path, exact, render} ) => {
    const user = null;
    if(user !== null)
    {
        return <Route 
            exact={exact}
            path={path}
            render={render}
        />
    }
    else 
    {
        return <Redirect to='/login' />
    }
}

Answer (score 2):

Simply !

```
  export default function RouteComponent() {
  const user = useContext(UserContext);

  return (
    <Router>
      {user.islogin ? (
        <div className="main_container">
          <Nav />
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/">
              <Home />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/NewActiv">
              <NewActiv />
            </Route>
          </Switch>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/">
            <Login />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      )}
    </Router>
  );
}
export default function RouteComponent() {
  const user = useContext(UserContext);

  return (
    <Router>
      {user.islogin ? (
        <div className="main_container">
          <Nav />
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/">
              <Home />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/NewActiv">
              <NewActiv />
            </Route>
          </Switch>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/">
            <Login />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      )}
    </Router>
  );
}
```