# want to assign permisssions to the component data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to ReactJS. I have 3 components and I want to assign permission to the the admin from owner component. When the permission is allowed in that component, the admin can edit or remove the content of the component. I am not finding a clean way to achieve that.

Comment: please post the code you have and where in particular you are struggling

Comment: i have not started at i am confused how to do it

Comment: You can use this as an example, if you are not using react router, thats fine, you can still apply the same principles - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57660849/how-to-use-private-route-using-react-router