# Private React Router is not preventing from accessing to dashboard after logout

Tags: reactjs, authentication, react-router, logout

I'm trying to implement login/logout auth with JWT and `fastapi`
Everything is working fine, when I press logout it set the token to null in the local storage and redirect the user to the login page,
but when I try to access the dashboard again from the URL it allows me
I checked the token in the local storage and it is null but not removed

```
//ProtectedRoute:

function ProtectedRoute({ component: Component, ...restOfProps }) {
  
  const isToken = localStorage.getItem("awesomeLeadsToken");
  console.log("this", isToken);
  return (
    <Route
      {...restOfProps}
      render={(props) =>
        isToken  ? <Component {...props} /> : <Redirect to="/login" /> }
    />
  );
}

//Logout:

const handleLogout =() =>{
    window.localStorage.removeItem("awesomeLeadsToken");
    setToken(null)
    window.location.href = '/login';
}
```

Comment: Try like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/57661107/311255, just return the route.

Comment: thanks for replying. I tried the solution in this link but it didn't work for me. I solved it by adding authenticated state in addition to the token state.